# reshape a data frame to show the change of ranking

Tags: python, pandas

```
         2010 2011 2012
     1   a    b   c 
     2   b    c   a
     3   c    a   b
```

Suppose I have a data frame as above,
the index is the ranking (a ranked 1st in 2010).
I want to reshape the data frame, like

```
    2010 2011 2012
a    1     3    2
b    2     1    3
c
```

so that the values become the ranking.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you replace the dots by expected values in the result dataframe? I am not sure I have correctly understood what you want...

Comment: So what should be under the years, the frequency of year 2010 with value a? In that case you could use groupby.

Answer (score 0):

If unique values per rows is possible use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index').pivot('value','variable','index')
print (df)
variable  2010  2011  2012
value                     
a          1.0   3.0   2.0
b          2.0   1.0   3.0
c          3.0   2.0   1.0
```